# Android: is there any better view to display HTML data string?

Tags: android, html

I have a HTML string with "strong ul ol br h" tags and so on, and I want to display the html data in the app.

The problem is, 
using TextView with Html.fromHtml() doesn't work for "ul" "ol" tags, 
and WebView doesn't work with padding and margin,  I really need it.

So is there any better choice to render HTML string?

Comment: "WebView doesn't work with padding and margin" -- sure it does. Put it in the HTML, if nothing else. `WebView` also supports margins at the widget level (though I haven't tried padding). "So is there any better choice to render HTML string?" -- parse it yourself and use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to handle things like your bullets, then use the result with a `TextView`.

Comment: It's a web view, it should handle essentially anything webby you put in there.